# Comparator : Equals method functionality

Tags: java, compare, comparator

Actually i am going through one of the tutorial in which it mentioned that when we need to implement the `Comparator` interface we can override `equals` method. however it is not necessary to override.

So just to understand better, I override the method as follows:

Test.java

```
 import java.util.TreeSet;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        TreeSet t = new TreeSet(new MyComparator());
        t.add(1);
        t.add(1);
        t.add(2);
        System.out.println(t);
    }
}
```

MyComparator.java

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class MyComparator
    implements Comparator
{
    @Override
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2)
    {
        Integer i1 = (Integer) o1;
        Integer i2 = (Integer) o2;
        return i1.compareTo(i2);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o1)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

For other scenario

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class MyComparator
    implements Comparator
{
    @Override
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2)
    {
        Integer i1 = (Integer) o1;
        Integer i2 = (Integer) o2;
        return i1.compareTo(i2);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o1)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

No matter what I return from `equals` method either true or false .. it is returning the same `TreeSet` value.

Can anyone can clear up the concept of functionality of `equals` method please?

Comment: Equality is talking about *the objects being compared*, not comparing the comparators themselves. (And use generics--you're getting warnings for not doing so, and you should pay attention.)

Comment: @SHG Wrong. It has to use comparisons to know where in the tree to insert (and whether there are duplicates).

Comment: Can you provide a link to the tutorial you're using?

Answer (score 10):

Implementing the `equals()` method on a `Comparator` allows you to indicate that one comparator provides the same ordering as another comparator.  It has nothing to do with how your elements are sorted.  It is a very advanced and extremely rarely needed functionality.  You are highly unlikely to ever encounter a situation where your comparator's `equals()` method will actually be invoked. I would suggest that you ignore it.

***Edit:***

As an example of the very rare kind of circumstances under which `Comparator` `equals()` might be used:

If you look at [the source code of `TreeMap`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/TreeMap.java) in function `PutAll(Map)` they have an optimization which checks whether the given map is also a `TreeMap`, and if so, then they check whether that map's comparator is equal to this map's comparator, and if so, they perform an optimized insertion of data which is known to already be sorted in the right order; otherwise, they delegate to `super.PutAll(Map)` which adds the items one by one.

Comment: Why would you need to compare two `Comparators` ?

Comment: @fg78nc I can't think of any scenario where I personally would need that, but apparently the creators of the `Comparator` interface decided that there is sufficient need to see if one `Comparator` provides the same ordering as another as to warrant including the `equals()` method in the `Comparator` interface.

Comment: @fg78nc I added an example. It did not take me long to find one, only 5 years.

Answer (score 5):

`equals()` method of the class, `Comparator` and `Comparator` require equals consistency because some Java collection classes may behave unpredictably if the `compareTo()` and `equals()` methods are not returning consistent results.

Java uses == operator to compare two primitives and/or to check if two variables refer to the same object. 
Example :

```
String apple1 = new String("apple");
String apple2 = new String("apple"); 
System.out.println(apple1.equals(apple2)); // true

StringBuilder app1 = new StringBuilder("apple"); 
StringBuilder app2 = new StringBuilder("apple"); 
System.out.println(app1.equals(app2));   // false
```

As you can see we get different behavior. Why is that? This happens because String class implements an equals() method, which checks that the values are the same. On the other hand, StringBuilder does not implement equals() method, instead it uses the implementation of equals() provided by `Object` class. And implementation provided(inherited) by `Object` class does only simply checks if the two referred objects are the same.

So to check if two objects are equivalent Java uses the `equals()` method and whenever you introduce your own type you must overrides `equals()` method if you do not want to rely on `Object` class implementation of `equals()` method

Let's for example introduce our own type : simple class Apple

```
public class Apple  {

    private int weight;
    private int cost;
    private String color;
```

Now how do would you decide if two apples are equal? By color, by weight, by price or something else? This is why you need to supply explicitly your own equals method, so objects of your type can be compared for equality.

Example below compares two `Apple` object for equality, and says that two object are equal if they belong to the same 'Apple' class and if their weight and cost is the same. Notice we do not compare by color, we assume that color is irrelevant in our case, which means that we accept the fact that apples of different colors, but with the same weight and same cost are considered equals.

```
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if ( !(obj instanceof Apple)) return false;    
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Apple other = (Apple) obj;
        if (cost != other.cost and weight != other.weight )
            return false;
        return true;
    }
```

You can implement any logic you like for your `equals()` method. Java `equals()` method is very important and it provides contract or important rules developer shall follow. I will not list them, you get them from [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)), they are logic and pretty straight forward.

There is another contract of `equals()` - whenever you override `equals()`, you are also expected to override `hashCode()` method. The reason behind that is because hashcode is used internally by some of Java collections, when object is stored as a key in the map.

Hashcode is a number that categorizes object into categories. Imagine you are given various sorts of apples(red, green, yellow) and asked to give them back when asked for particular sort. It would be much efficient and faster if you categorize them, put each in a different buckets accordingly and whenever asked for particular sort (for simplicity let's say red apple), and as you have already sorted and categorized them, you can retrieve them much faster. Hope it is clear now why do you need to implement `hashcode()`. `hashcode()` has it's own contract or rules same as `equals()` method. They pretty much make common sense :

First, result of `hashcode()` within same program shall not change. What it means that in your `hascode()` calculations you should not include variable that my change during execution of a program. For example if cost of Apple's is mutable, i.e. it may change, it is not good idea to include them into hashcode() calculation, otherwise results would be inconsistent.

Second rule says, that when called with two objects, if `equals()` returns true then  calling `hashCode()` on each of those objects must retrieve the same result. But if `equals()` returns false when called with two objects, calling `hashCode()` on each of those objects does not necessary have to return a different result. Confusing? Why? Because `hashCode()` results are not required to be unique when called on unequal objects - you may put two unequal object in one bucket.

Now regarding `Comparator` - it is easier to understand it's logic when you introduce your own type, instead of using built-in types.

For example let's say we have class `Apple` with two attributes : `weight` and `price` and want to put out object this type into sorted collection `TreeSet`.

```
public class Apple  {

    private int weight;
    private int cost;
```

Now how do you want this apples to be sorted inside collection - do you want to sort them by `weight` or by `price`? How shall compiler decide?

Supplying appropriate `Comparator`or `Comparable` allows you to pass your intent.
Let's try to add object to collection.

```
  public class Apple {

    private int weight;
    private int cost;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Apple redApple = new Apple();
    redApple.setCost(10);
    redApple.setWeight(2);

    Apple greenApple = new Apple();
    greenApple.setCost(12);
    greenApple.setWeight(3);

    Set<Apple> apples = new TreeSet<>();
    apples.add(redApple);
    apples.add(greenApple);

    System.out.println(apples);
   } 

    public int getWeight() {
       return weight;
    }

   public void setWeight(int weight) {
       this.weight = weight;
    }

   public int getCost() {
       return cost;
   }

   public void setCost(int cost) {
     this.cost = cost;
    }

   @Override
   public String toString() {
       return "Apple [weight=" + weight + ", cost=" + cost + "]";
    }
}
```

If you run above code you will get RuntimeError : `Apple cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable`, because compiler has to way to figure out how do you want to compare your apples. 
So let's fix it :
  Let's implement `Comparable` interface

```
  public class Apple implements Comparable<Apple> {
```

and override `compareTo` method

```
 @Override
    public int compareTo(Object obj) {

        int cost = ((Apple) obj).getCost();
        return this.getCost() - cost; // sorting in ascending order.

        // change to this to sort in Descending order
        // return cost - this.getCost();
    }
```

Now with this changes, let's run our code :

```
[Apple [weight=2, cost=10], Apple [weight=3, cost=12]]
```

Our collection is sorted by cost in ascending order.

Now what if you don't have access to `Apple` class and you can't change source code to implement `Comparable`.

This is where `Comparator` helps.

Remove `implements Comparable`, as we assume we can't modify this class

```
public class Apple {
```

and remove method

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Apple [weight=" + weight + ", cost=" + cost + "]";
}
```

Add comparator implementation :

```
  public class AppleComparator implements Comparator<Apple> {

        @Override
        public int compare(Apple app1, Apple app2) {
            return app1.getCost() - app2.getCost();
        }

}
```

Now I can just supply `Comparator` to collection to express my intend

```
Set<Apple> apples = new TreeSet<>(new AppleComparator());
```

Collection again will be sorted by cost, accordingly to supplied Comparator.
So we need to supply either `Comparator` or `Comparable` in order to get them stored in the collection, particularly in `TreeSet`.

Now regarding your question : There is no connection between `Comparator` and `equals()` method . There is only required consistency between `Comparable` (compareTo() method ) and `equals()` method.

Example - in above mentioned `Apple` class, in version that implements Comparable, 
we introduce new logic for determining equality. The `compareTo()` method returns 0 if two objects are equal, while your `equals()` method returns true if two objects are equal.

A natural ordering that uses `compareTo()` required to be consistent with equals iff x.equals(y) is true whenever x.compareTo(y) equals 0. So you have to make your `Comparable` class consistent with equals because some Java collection classes may behave unpredictably if the `compareTo()` and `equals()` methods are not returning consistent results.

The following example shows compareTo() method that is not consistent with equals:

```
public class Apple implements Comparable<Apple> { 

private int weight;
private int cost;
private String color;

public boolean equals(Object obj) {
   if(!(obj instanceof Apple)) { 
      return false;
  }
   Apple other = (Apple) obj; 
    return this.weight == other.weight;
  }

public int compareTo(Apple obj) {
    return this.cost.compareTo(obj.cost); }
 }
```

If we want to sort Apple objects by cost, but cost may not be unique. There could two objects with the same cost. Therefore, the return value of `compareTo()` might not be 0 when comparing two equal `Apple` objects, which mean that this `compareTo()` method is not consistent with `equals()`.

Comment: The first sentence of this answer is incorrect.  `Comparator<T>::compare(:T, :T)` must be consistent with `T::equals(:T)`.  It has nothing to do with `Comparator<T>::equals(Comparator<T>)`.

Comment: I did not say anything on Comparator’s equal.

Comment: That's how I'm reading it; perhaps you could rewrite the first couple sentences to be less ambiguous.

Comment: better if we avoid writing !(obj instanceof Apple) this logic in equals method, because instanceof operator gives true for parent object also.

Comment: So many words about Java basics and nothing in regard to the purpose of `Comparator.equals()`. Cast i--.

Answer (score 1):

The `equals()` method that you have override, is in the `MyComparator class` so it will be used if you need to compare 2 instance of `Mycomparator` ;)

And that's not what you're doing, you are comparing `int` so yes the `compare()` method is usefull because it's the one which will be used for `sorting` the `Treeset` but the equals method here won't be used

In 99% of the time, you don't need to `override equals` method in classes that `implements` `Comparator`, because they are here just to `compare` values not themself to another one, and in fact because most of the time they have to attributes, you won't have  `comparator` equals.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you are linking the `Comparator` and the `equals()` method. The `interfaces` like `Comparable` and `Comparator`are used for giving a comparison mechanism, like if you are putting data into a `collection` which is designed for `sorting purpose`, then it should have a comparison mechanism. Here is an example

```
package snippet;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

class Person {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String code;
    private double salary;
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }
    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }
    public double getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }
    public void setSalary(double salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {         
        if(obj != null && (obj instanceof Person)) {
            Person other = (Person) obj;
            return this.code.equals(other.getCode());
        }
        return false;
    }
    public Person(int id, String name, String code, double salary) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.code = code;
        this.salary = salary;
    }
}

public class EqualsMethodImpl
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<Person> set = new TreeSet<Person>();
        Person p1 = new Person(1, "Sam", "M-1-SAM-50", 50000.00);
        Person p2 = new Person(2, "Diaz", "M-1-SAM-35", 35000.00);
        Person p3 = new Person(3, "Remy", "M-1-SAM-100", 100000.00);
        Person p4 = new Person(4, "Cesar", "M-1-SAM-80", 80000.00);
        Person p5 = new Person(5, "Rino", "M-1-SAM-5", 5000.00);

        set.add(p1);
        set.add(p2);
        set.add(p3);
        set.add(p4);
        set.add(p5);

        printPersons(set);
    }

    private static void printPersons(Set<Person> set) {
        System.out.println("Id\tName\tCode\t\tSalary");
        Iterator<Person> perItr = set.iterator();       
        while(perItr.hasNext()) {
            Person p = perItr.next();
            System.out.println(p.getId()+"\t"+p.getName()+"\t"+p.getCode()+"\t"+p.getSalary());
        }
    }
}
```

While you running this code you will get `ClasCastException` at line `set.add(p1);`, why because the collection `TreeSet` is confused about on which attribute of `Peron` class should it do the sorting. That's where the `interfaces` like `Comparable` and `Comparator` have their significance.

Add this code to your `Person` class

```
public int compareTo(Person other) {
    Double person1Salary = this.getSalary();
    Double person2Salary = other.getSalary();
    return person1Salary.compareTo(person2Salary);
}
```

by making your class Comparable type like `Person implements Comparable<Person>`

So by this code you are explaining the collection on which attribute we need to do the sorting. So when you print the content of `Set` it will be ordered on the base salary (ascending by default).

The Wrapper classes like `Byte, Short, Integer, Long, Float, Double` and other predefied classes like `String` all are implementing `Comaparable` interface and that's why you can simply pass them to a Sortable collection.

Now coming to `equals` method, it is used to check the equality of two objects, the traditional `equals` method inherited from Object class will check equality based on address locations. So take a case in Person class where I haven't overrided `equals` method and I'm writing a code like this

```
Person p1 = new Person(1, "Sam", "M-1-SAM-50", 50000.00);
Person p2 = new Person(1, "Sam", "M-1-SAM-50", 50000.00);
System.out.println(p1.equals(p2));
```

It will return false because both are two different objects placed in two different address locations, but we know that the objects are having data of the same person. That's the place where we override `equals()` method like I did in my `Person` class based on `Person code`. In that case `System.out.println(p1.equals(p2));` will print true because the codes are equal. `equals()` method helps us in finding the duplicates. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The equals method is used to check the Equality of two comparators i.e in equals method you can specify what makes ComparatorA and ComparatorB Identical, it has nothing to do with the elements that are sorted using these comparators.

Comment: This answer was written one and a half year after my answer, but it is saying the same thing without adding anything new. If you have some improvement to suggest with regards to wording, the recommended approach is to edit the question whose wording you think you can improve, or add a comment suggesting how the wording could be improved.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to sort the values of Treeset. TreesSet elements are automatically sorted in ascending order.

```
class TreeSet1{  
   public static void main(String args[]){  
       //Creating and adding elements  
        TreeSet<String> al=new TreeSet<String>();  
        al.add("Ravi");  
        al.add("Vijay");  
        al.add("Ravi");  
        al.add("Ajay");  
        //Traversing elements  
       Iterator<String> itr=al.iterator();  
          while(itr.hasNext()){  
             System.out.println(itr.next());  
          }  
    }
```

}

output=
Ajay
Ravi
Vijay

Answer (score -1):

First of all, *please* use generics. With the added compile-time type-safety, your code will be more robust, which in turn will make your life (and that of those who read your code) much easier (if you know what you're doing, of course). Your class `MyComparator` implements the raw type `Comparator`, which means that by just looking at its type declaration, you have no way of knowing which types of objects it compares. You have to look at the source (or, alternatively, at the documentation) in order to find out that, if any object that is not a subtype of `Integer` is passed, a `ClassCastException` will be thrown *at runtime*. On the other hand, if it were to implement `Comparator<Integer>`, the compiler will never let it come to this, because then, the method signature of the `compare` method would read `compare(Integer, Integer)` instead of `compare(Object, Object)`, meaning that, if an object is not an `Integer`, it can never be passed to the method in the first place, which is something that can already be ensured *at compile time*.

Having that out of the way, you seem to be confusing `Comparator` and `Comparable`. A `Comparable` means that something has a "natural ordering", as Java calls it. An integer is a simple example, because a number is inherently quantifiable, so comparing two numbers is unambiguous (`Double.NaN` is a special case, but that is another matter). Thus, `Integer` implements `Comparable<Integer>` (but not `Comparable<Number>`, interestingly). However, occasions might arise when you want to compare things that are not inherently quantifiable. Arun Sudhakaran used the idea of comparing persons as an example in his answer. He suggested making the `Person` class implement `Comparable<Person>` so that you can pass it to a `TreeSet<Person>`, but this seems counterintuitive to me, for the precise reason that a person is not inherently quantifiable. You might want to sort the persons by their salary, but this quantification is not inherent to a person, it is only specific to your particular intention in that situation. So this would be a use case for a `Comparator<Person>`. You can sort the persons by their age, salary, height, whatever, by providing a respective `Comparator<Person>`, but a `Person` is not by itself comparable.

Note that the two are not mutually exclusive – you can also compare objects that implement `Comparable` by using a `Comparator` whose ordering differs from the natural ordering of the `Comparable` objects.

Now when the javadocs talk about comparisons being "consistent with equals", then "equals" in this context always refers to the `equals(Object)` method *of the object to be compared*, may that object implement `Comparable` itself or just be compared to another object with a `Comparator`. In other words, if a comparison method (be that a `Comparator` or a natural ordering) deems two objects equal that are also equal according to their respective `equals(Object)` method, and vice versa, this comparison method is "consistent with equals" This has nothing to do with the `equals(Object)` method of a `Comparator`, which was already pointed out by Mike Nakis (unless you want to compare `Comparator`s).

An example of a natural ordering that is inconsistent with equals is that of the class `BigDecimal`. Two `BigDecimal`s representing `2.0` and `2.00` will *not* be equal according to `BigDecimal.equals(Object)`, but they *will* be considered equal by their natural ordering (i.e. by `compareTo(BigDecimal)`).